# How to transfer data via query params of a POST request, using Angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular12

I am facing an annoying issue. When trying to pass data using HttpParams from Angular to backend (ASP.NET Core Web API), the backend parameters are all null. I am using Angular 12 version.

Here is my code:

`Component.ts`:

```
nn:string;
price = "200";
username = 700;
Id = 0;
...
tokenizeUserDetails() {
{
...
     
     let params = new HttpParams();
     params = params.append('Id', 0);
     params = params.append('nn', payload.nonce);
     params = params.append('price', this.price);
     params = params.append('username', this.username);
     console.log(params);
  
     this.http.post(this.baseUrl+ 'paypal',params).subscribe({
      next: response => { 
        console.log(this.CToken);
        this.CToken = response;
      },
...
```

Backend:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class paypalController : BaseApiController
{
   ...

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task <paypalDto> Create([FromQuery] paypalDto order)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

`PaypalDto.cs`:

```
public class paypalDto
{   public int  Id { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; } 
    public string nn { get; set; }
    public int username { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application and pass the data from Angular to the backend, all parameters are null:

[image]

But by using `console.log()` for testing purpose, I found correctly data in my browser console:

[image]

I have tried to pass by using fours parameters but Angular showed an error for overload purpose. That's why I am trying to pass those data using HttpParams but I am facing unexpected and annoying output. I am an absolute beginner. How to resolve this issue please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Pass data to API with query parameters.**

Since you want to send the request by passing data with query parameters, modify the API action to receive the query parameters with `[FromQuery] attribute.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task <paypalDto> Create([FromQuery] int Id, [FromQuery] string price, [FromQuery] string nn, [FromQuery] int username)
```

And append `params` object into `httpOptions` object. Pass the `httpOptions` object in `post` method.

```
let params = new HttpParams();
...

let httpOptions = {
  params: params
};

this.http.post(this.baseUrl+ 'paypal', null, httpOptions).subscribe(...);
```

---

**Solution 2: Post data to API with Request Body**

Since it is a POST method, you should utilize it to post data with the request body.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task <paypalDto> Create([FromBody] paypalDto order)
```

```js
let obj = {
  Id: 0,
  nn: payload.nonce,
  price: this.price,
  username: this.username
};
  
this.http.post(this.baseUrl+ 'paypal', obj).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

#### How to transfer data via query-params of a POST-request

**Frontend**

`HttpParams` are part of the third argument of `this.http.post`. In your case the second argument might be `null` instead:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
                    .set('id', '1')
                    .set('name', 'Robert');

this.http.post(url, null, { params });
```

**Backend**

In your backend you need to catch the properties one by one, not as an object:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveUser([FromQuery] string id, [FromQuery] string name)
{
   var id = id;
   var name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Made changes as per below

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task <paypalDto> Create([FromBody] paypalDto order)
{
     ...
}
```

In Angular Side

```
 const body =  {
   'Id': 0,
   'nn': payload.nonce,
   'price': this.price,
   'username': this.username
  }

 this.http.post(this.baseUrl+ 'paypal', body).subscribe({
  next: response => { 
    console.log(this.CToken);
    this.CToken = response;
  },
```